# Split date-time column into Date and time variables

Tags: r, date, datetime, split

I have a 'date-time column 'Start' in the format "Y-m-d H:M:S". I want to split this column into a "Date" and a "time" column.

I have tried the following:

```
df$Date <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Start), " "), "[", 1)
df$Time <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Start), " "), "[", 2)
```

This works, however, if I use the function `str(df)`

```
# 'data.frame':   18363 obs. of  19 variables:<br>
#  $ Start    : Factor w/ 67 levels "2013-09-01 08:07:41.000",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# [snip]
```

So now I only need to know how to convert the time and date from `factor` to 'time' and 'date'.

Comment: Use `sapply` rather than `lapply`. When `sapply` encounters a result that is "regular" it returns a vector or matrix. `lapply` always retruns a list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Start) # already got this one from the answers above
df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Start), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Use `as.Date` to convert 'Start' to a variables of class `Date`. For the time variable, we first convert 'Start' to `POSIXct`. Then use `format` to extract the time component as a string.

Answer (score 33):

How about

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Start)

df$Time <- format(df$Start,"%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: This gives me this error..:
Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument

Comment: You have df$Start of type "character", it isn't a timestamp. Use the class() function to check. You should convert the string to a timestamp before applying the functions above.

Comment: Thanks, R read it as a factor. I already got a column with the dates that in fact really has "Date" as a class. However, now I am struggling with the time. I used: df$time <- as.POSIXlt(strptime(df$Start, format = "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ]")) but it won't work.. Still trying!

Comment: strptime(as.character(df$Start),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")?

Comment: Tried that one, but now it gives me as an error that the "argument 'format' is missing, with no default"..

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your data looks similar to this with one `datetime` column and many other columns

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, datetime = as.POSIXct(c('2019-02-01 01:00:00', 
                 '2019-02-01 02:00:00', '2019-02-01 03:00:00', 
                 '2019-02-01 04:00:00', '2019-02-01 05:00:00')))

df
#  a            datetime
#1 1 2019-02-01 01:00:00
#2 2 2019-02-01 02:00:00
#3 3 2019-02-01 03:00:00
#4 4 2019-02-01 04:00:00
#5 5 2019-02-01 05:00:00
```

We can split the column on whitespace (or any other delimiter present) to get a separate date and time columns which can be done using `tidyr::separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, datetime, c("date", "time"), sep = " ")
#  a       date     time
#1 1 2019-02-01 01:00:00
#2 2 2019-02-01 02:00:00
#3 3 2019-02-01 03:00:00
#4 4 2019-02-01 04:00:00
#5 5 2019-02-01 05:00:00
```

If we want to keep the original column (`datetime`) we can add `remove = FALSE`.

---

`separate` is superseded and we can now use `separate_wider_*` functions to split the columns.

```
separate_wider_delim(df, datetime, delim = " ", names = c("date", "time"))
```

Answer (score 6):

By seeing your column format, I'd say you could use as.POSIXct to properly format your column, and then use format() to extract the desired data.

This is the code I use when splitting a DateTime column,

```
df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Start,format="%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")

df$Date <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Start,format="%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),"%Y:%m:%d")
```

Answer (score 3):

You might prefer to do something like this, avoiding the use of an `lapply` loop which isn't really necessary (but it's not a bad thing either!)...

```
#  If we had this data...
df <- data.frame( Start = c( "13:11:2013 15:39" , "13:11:2013 16:15" , "13:11:2013 17:52" ) )

#  We can directly make two columns from the split strings without
#  using a loop by call 'do.call'..
new <- do.call( rbind , strsplit( as.character( df$Start ) , " " ) )
#     [,1]         [,2]   
#[1,] "13:11:2013" "15:39"
#[2,] "13:11:2013" "16:15"
#[3,] "13:11:2013" "17:52"


#  Cbind them to the original data liek so...
cbind( df , Date = new[,2] , Time = new[,1] )
#             Start  Date       Time
#1 13:11:2013 15:39 15:39 13:11:2013
#2 13:11:2013 16:15 16:15 13:11:2013
#3 13:11:2013 17:52 17:52 13:11:2013
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, but that's probably due to the fact R read it in as a factor.. Thanks!

Comment: @JalouHuntjens `as.character` should take care of that. The data in my example is also `factor`. Can you add `str( df )` to the OP so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: @JalouHuntjens what was the error you got from running my code on your data? It *should* work.

Comment: it just gives me a list  with the following:5259  48.88   1 13740310 2013-09-04 08:14:11.000. If I use str() then it still reads it as a factor, also it does not split the rows.. I have no idea of what I am doing wrong. Anyways, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are open for a non-`base` alternative, you may use `data.table::IDateTime` which

> takes a date-time input and returns a data table with columns date and time

...of class `IDate`* and `ITime`** respectively:

```
x = as.POSIXct("2013-09-01 08:07:41") + 0:2
IDateTime(x)
#         idate    itime
# 1: 2013-09-01 08:07:41
# 2: 2013-09-01 08:07:42
# 3: 2013-09-01 08:07:43
```

---

> *`IDate` is a date class derived from `Date`. It has the same internal representation as the `Date` class, except the storage mode is integer.

> **`ITime` is a time-of-day class stored as the integer number of seconds in the day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this method. It works very good

```
format(mdy(df_5star$Date4)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This could use a bit more to be a good answer. The question asks to create both a date column and a time column, but this answer only creates one. Also, you're missing a `)`, and when using functions not included in base R (like `mdy()`), you should mention the needed packages (`lubridate`, presumably).