# How to split columns in R

Tags: r

I have around 10k records. There is a variable named `date_time` with data in the following format `2013-01-07 10:17:08`.

I need to split the column and arrive at a derived variable to identify year and month separately.

Comment: What `class` is your variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split date time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292438/split-date-time)

Comment: Check out `separate` from the package `tidyr`, https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Use "as.POSIXlt(date_time)$year" and "months(date_time)" to obtain the desired year and month.  I would advise against trying to manually split the a time object unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lubridate` package to convert the 'date_time' column to `POSIXct` class and extract the `year` and `month` from the output

```
library(lubridate)
v1 <- ymd_hms(df1$date_time)
transform(df1, Year= year(v1), Month = month(v1))
#            date_time Year Month
#1 2013-01-07 10:17:08 2013     1
#2 2013-01-08 10:18:08 2013     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(date_time=c('2013-01-07 10:17:08', 
         '2013-01-08 10:18:08'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```