# convert string date to date and time in R

Tags: r

I have following date format in R as string datatype

```
6/9/2017 3:53:00 AM
```

Which I can Convert to date with following format

```
df$date<- as.POSIXct(df$date, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
df$date<- as.POSIXct(df$date, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

which gives me following format in R

```
2017-09-06 3:53:00
```

But,when I have following as a date string

```
8/3/2017
```

and,when I run above code it gives me `NA` value against it. 
I want following format when its only date

```
2017-03-08 00:00:00
```

How can I do it in R ?

Comment: did you try `strsplit`. This will help you

Comment: Possible Duplicate `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292438/split-date-time`

Comment: This will work `as.POSIXct("8/3/2017", format="%d/%m/%Y")` but without the time as `00:00:00`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292438/split-date-time)