# R- Create a new field applying condition on a Date field

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I am new in R.  I am working with windows 10.  I have R Studio and  R version 3.5.0.

I have a table with one field dateTime format.

```
2012-02-02 10:04:00
2012-08-13 11:38:00
2012-07-13 14:00:00
2012-09-26 08:45:00
2012-10-24 05:39:00
2012-02-03 03:33:00
2012-05-02 06:30:00
2012-06-27 09:00:00
2012-07-09 10:16:00
2012-11-22 13:13:00
```

I need to create a new field that splits the data between summer and winter:
From May to September would be Summer and from October to April would be Winter. Based on the result of this new field, create another one that separates the data between times of the day:  morning, noon, afternoon and night for summer and the same for winter. The conditions would be:

For Summer

```
     *  Morning Summer: 5 am – 10 am 
     *  Noon Summer: 10 am -12 pm 
     *  Afternoon Summer: 12 pm -8 pm 
     *  Night summer 8 pm – 5 am
```

For Winter

```
     *  Morning Winter: 7 am – 11 am 
     *  Noon Winter: 11 am -12 pm 
     *  Afternoon Winter: 12 pm -4 pm 
     *  Night Winter 4 pm – 7 am
```

the result would be something like this:

```
 date                 | season |    time Of Day
'2012-02-02 10:04:00' | winter | morning
'2012-08-13 11:38:00' | summer | noon
'2012-07-13 14:00:00' | summer | afternoon
'2012-09-26 08:45:00' | summer | morning
'2012-10-24 05:39:00' | winter | night
'2012-02-03 03:33:00' | winter | night
'2012-05-02 06:30:00' | summer | morning
'2012-12-27 09:00:00' | winter | morning
'2012-07-09 10:16:00' | summer | morning
'2012-11-22 13:13:00' | winter | afternoon
```

For the first case, (split between summer and winter) I tried to use case_when, but it did not work:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(season = case_when(
    month(.$date) > 4 & month(.$date)< 10 ~ "summer",
    month(.$date) < 5 & month(.$date) > 10 ~ "winter"
    ))
```

> ```
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>   Evaluation error: do not know how to convert 'x' to class 
> <U+0093>POSIXlt<U+0094>.
> ```

I tried to find something about the error, but to be honest I did not get how to solve the problem. I tried to use library "lubridate" but still doesn't work.

Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 df %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.POSIXct) %>% 
          mutate(season = case_when(
                          month(date) > 4 & month(date) < 10 ~ "summer",
                          month(date) < 5 & month(date) > 10 ~ "winter"
        ))
```

## Data

```
 data <- read.table(text="
                       date
               '2012-02-02 10:04:00'

               '2012-08-13 11:38:00'

               '2012-07-13 14:00:00'

               '2012-09-26 08:45:00'

              ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: `season = case_when(
                 month(date) > 4 & month(date) < 10 ~ "summer",
                 TRUE ~ "winter")` works as well. No need for the .$ in front of date.

Comment: @phiver Thanks noted.

Comment: If I understood correctly,  the ` is.character, as.POSIXct` part, makes a transformation in the data, from character to POSIXct.  Well, when I perform your suggestion with your data, it works. But with my table (even when the date is also defined as character), gives me this error:              
          Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Please double check your variable carefully as may some of them are not in this '2012-02-02 10:04:00' format.

Comment: any suggestion of how to deal with it @A.Suliman? I tried using na.omit , filter (!is.na(data), and na.rm=TRUE.   And so far, no success

Comment: It is not missing value, I was able to reproduce your error when change '2012-08-13 11:38:00' to '2012-08.13' in **data**. What `as.Date(data$date)` return. Is there any NA after run `as.Date(data$date)` or any error message

Comment: Yeah A. Suliman, I did the same experiment, and I had the same error, but using the transformation you mentioned, it makes it work!! thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Just for completeness, my next step, it would be to check the variable `date` structure using `grepl('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\s{1}[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}', data$date)` to see if there are any recoreds have different structure.

Comment: @A.Suliman, thanks for the extra tip. Im dealing right now with calculation on Time (the second part of my question).  I tried converting the dateTime only into Time but I only get NA.      ' data1$date1 <- format(data1$date,"%H:%M:%S")'  or 'data1$date1  <- format(as.POSIXct(data1$date,format="%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"),"%H:%M:%S")
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292438/split-date-time#19292771   and http://cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/time.html  The last one explains how to make calculations on time but it considers also the date, Im trying to catalog time into a part of day,  Do you have a hint

Comment: The second solution can get what you want, just I think in your case years, months and days are separated using `-` not `:`. So, you can try `format(as.POSIXct(data1$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), format="%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @ A.Sullivan ...Holly, What a shame!!!, I never saw that coming! Problem solved thanks :)

Comment: Don't be, we all been there before. You are most welcome ;)